# How can I turn this into a DELETE statement in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a select statement which returns duplicates in a table. I want to now be able to delete these duplicates. How can I do this with ORACLE SQL?

```
SELECT
  c1.name                     AS c1name,
  c2.name                     AS c2name,
  c1.cy_code                  AS c1country,
  c2.cy_code                  AS c2country,
  c1.latitude                 AS c1lat,
  c1.longitude                AS c1long,
  c2.latitude                 AS c2lat,
  c2.longitude                AS c2long,
  calc_distance(c1.latitude,
                c1.longitude,
                c2.latitude,
                c2.longitude) AS distance
FROM city_temp c1,
  city_temp c2
WHERE c2.name = c1.name
  AND c2.cy_code = c1.cy_code
  AND calc_distance(c1.latitude, c1.longitude, c2.latitude, c2.longitude) = 0
  AND c1.latitude = c2.latitude
  AND c1.longitude = c2.longitude;
```

Comment: Just a remark: Given that you restrict c1.latitude = c2.latitude and c1.longitude = c2.longitude, isn't calc_distance(c1.latitude, c1.longitude, c2.latitude, c2.longitude) always zero then?

Comment: Also, the table only has around 8000 rows but when I perform the search, it gives me over 10,000 rows. Why is this and how can I counter this?

Comment: Without knowing how your data actually looks like and how you decide which rows are duplicates, this is hard to tell. Can you post the table definition and some sample data?

Comment: This is a self select (same table), but you dont exclude the record itself, so each record is joined with itself plus any duplicates. Use rowid to prevent joining a record with itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an exists clause to delete all rows that have equals with higher rowids:

```
delete from city_temp c1
where exists
(
  select *
  from city_temp c2
  where c2.name = c1.name 
    and c2.cy_code = c1.cy_code 
    and c2.latitude = c1.latitude 
    and c2.longitude = c1.longitude
    and calc_distance(c1.latitude, c1.longitude, c2.latitude, c2.longitude) = 0 
    and c2.rowid > c1.rowid
);
```

Comment: Is this any different to Narendra's query? I tested both and your one deleted 1148 rows whereas Narendra's deleted 1134 rows.

Comment: I take that back. I missed some things from your query!

Comment: Is there any way to perform a select on this before doing the delete so I can see what I will be deleting?

Comment: Yes, replace "delete from" with "select * from".

Answer (score 1):

you can try this if you could change the function calc_distance

```
DELETE FROM city_temp
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM city_temp
WHERE calc_distance(latitude, longitude)=0
GROUP BY name, cy_code, latitude,longitude
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rowid, you can perform this

```
DELETE FROM city_temp where rowid in (
            SELECT c1.rowid
            FROM city_temp c1, city_temp c2
            WHERE c2.name = c1.name  and c2.cy_code = c1.cy_code and calc_distance(c1.latitude, c1.longitude, c2.latitude, c2.longitude)=0 
                        and c1.latitude = c2.latitude and c1.longitude = c2.longitude)
```

Comment: It deleted all the rows :P

Comment: That means your query to find duplicates is not performing as expected.

Comment: @JohnathanAu : You should post the definition of duplicate rows in this context.

Comment: @merlin  max(c1.rowid) will delete only one row unless some grouping is specified.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to delete duplicate rows is

```
DELETE FROM table_name A WHERE ROWID > (
SELECT min(rowid) FROM table_name B
WHERE A.key_values = B.key_values)
```

Just plug your SELECT statement into it.

Or for ultimate speed on large data sets - you could copy the distinct data across into a temporary table, truncate the original, copy the data back and drop the temporary table.